# Асинхронная загрузка БД в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Сделал метод (в классе):

```
    public static async Task LoadBase()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", CommonData.pathBase)))
        {
            await con.OpenAsync();

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM `base`", con))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    sb.Append(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Создал `StringBuilder` и теперь хочу в него добавить все данные, чтобы потом вывести в `DataGridView`. Проблема, собственно, в этом и состоит, как добавить все строки куда-нибудь, чтобы дальше в форме вывести их в `DataGridView`?

Comment: ...зачем вам `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, я пытался записывать строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный вариант как мне это сделать.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, короче, вроде сделал)) только при вызове `Func.LoadBase();` пишет Предупреждение: по скольку этот вызов не ожидается, выполнение текущего метода продолжается до завершения вызова. Попробуйте применить оператор await к результату вызова. Я сделал так `Task.Run(async () => await Func.LoadBase());` предупреждение пропало, но данные теперь не загружает..

Comment: Сейчас нет времени отвечать подробно, но вам будет намного проще работать не со строками, а с нормальными данными. И почитайте о EF - информации хватает в том числе и на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы добавляете строки в StringBuilder?

Вы можете DataTable подвязать к DataGridView.

Вы можете так же на ходу генерировать DataGridView создавая строки столбцы с добавлением данные из БД.

Но учтите, что если вы хотите редактировать данные и отправлять их назад в базу, то вам придется много чего реализовывать ручками, а если бы вы использовали DataTable, то все это было бы доступно из коробки.

Comment: Спасибо, но я не хотел обращаться к `DataGridView` через класс, поэтому полученные данные пытался отправить на форму, что собственно и сделал (без StringBuilder). Сейчас проблема только в том, что я выше написал в комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальным решением даной задачи я вижу следующую реализацию:

1. ДатагридВью нужно переключить в виртуальный режим.
2. На RowNeeded ивенте подгружать нужную строку напрямую из базы

Соответственно если хотите редактировать и отправлять назад в базу, вам нужно так же хранить гдето показанные в данную секунду обьекты и при правке ячейки в датагриде -- делать правку в даном обьекте.

Еще я бы посоветовал заменить теперишний подход работы с базой на какой-нибудь микро-ОРМ вроде PetaPoco.